# Traverse a newly replaced node with babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I would like to add a statement before every function definition, e.g.

```
function a() {
  var b = function c() {};
}
```

becomes

```
foo(function a() {
  var b = foo(function c() {});
});
```

I am trying to achieve this with babel with the following visitor:

```
var findFunctionVisitor = {
  Function: function (path) {
    // Traversing further leads to infinite loop as same node is found again
    path.stop();
    var node = path.node;

    // Move every FunctionDeclaration to FunctionExpression
    var newNode = t.functionExpression(
      node.id,
      node.params,
      node.body,
      node.generator,
      node.async
    );

    path.replaceWith(
      t.CallExpression(instrumentationCall, [newNode])
    )

    // traverse the part in newNode.body
  }
};
```

If I don't stop the path the newly inserted FunctionExpression is found another time which leads to infinite recursion, so the stop is necessary. 
My exact problem is, that I don't know how to start the traversing of `newNode.body`, which I would need to get the inner function statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be done by using the [babel-traverse](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-traverse) module like this:

```
traverse(newNode, findFunctionVisitor, path.scope, path);
```

The third argument is a scope and the fourth is a parent path.